How do you solve the equation, $\sqrt{20889 + 4 k}=n$, for integers solutions?
I was interested in knowing the integer solutions for the equation $\sqrt{20889 + 4 k}=n$. When I input that equation into Wolfram Alpha, it says the integer solution is the pair $(k,n)=(34,145)$. I just want to know how the website got those numbers as the answer. If anyone could walk me through the steps to get that answer, it would be greatly appreciated.

Is there $4k^2$? Else there is infinite solutions

Hello! You can start from residual analysis. The first step would be taken.

as written you just need to look for odd squares greater than or equal to $20889$ (any odd square is $1$ mod $4$).

$$k=\frac{n^2-20889}{4}$$ , Since 4 doesn't divide 20889 & $n^2$ so n must be odd. So plug odd Integer Values for n to get an Integer Values for k.

Before asking any questions, search it in Approach Zero Website https://approach0.xyz/search/

Although I'm not certain how Wolfram-Alpha gets the solution $(k, n) = (34, 145)$ in particular, we can derive a general solution by observing residues.
From
$$20889 + 4k = n^2$$
we have by taking mod $4$ of both sides
$$1 \equiv n^2 \pmod 4$$
which implies that $n$ is positive and odd. In fact, any positive odd integer will work for $n$: setting $n = 2m - 1$, we have
$$k = m^2-m-5222$$
so we get the general solution $$(k, n) = (m^2 - m - 5222, 2m - 1)$$ for each positive integer $m$.

@jjagmath $n = \sqrt{20889 + 4k} \geq 0$ and $n$ being odd implies that $n$ is positive. And it is true that one can conclude $n$ is odd without taking mod $4$, but I wanted to demonstrate a more general principle of taking a modulus to obtain information on quadratic residues...
